# how to add extra GET parameters to post to url with add_rewrite_rule?

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

I have a blog that has a custom post type `article`, and the link is `http://example.com/article/lorem-ipsum`.

How can I use `add_rewrite_rule` to add a new link style to the same post `http://example.com/article/lorem-ipsum/readers` in such a way that the part `readers` add a `GET` parameter `&showReaders=true` to the page `http://example.com/article/lorem-ipsum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the add_rewrite_endpoint since what you are concerned with is at the end of the URL.

```
function wpseo331941_reader_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('readers', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES);
}
add_action('init', 'wpseo331941_reader_endpoint', 10, 0);
```

```
//When you want to check if the 'readers' is being used
if ( false !== get_query_var('readers', false) ){
    //....
}
```

*Note that the false !== has to be present, because your query var "readers" will have an empty string as its value.*